# Error: googleMobileAds/error-code-network-error The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity

Tags: android, react-native, expo, admob, eas

I've developed an app using React Native and Expo and wanted to add a banner ad to the end of it. When I run the app on a development build on an Android emulator the rest of the app runs without the app although there is space open where it should be and eventually I get this error [Error: [googleMobileAds/error-code-network-error] The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.]

```
app.json:

  {
    "expo": {
     ...
    }
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
      "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxx,
      "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxx"
    }
  }
```

```
  App.js:

  import {
    BannerAd,
    BannerAdSize,
    TestIds,
  } from "react-native-google-mobile-ads";

  const adUnitId = __DEV__
  ? TestIds.BANNER
  : "ca-app-pub-adunitid";
  
  return(
    <View>
      ... 
      <BannerAd
        unitId={TestIds.BANNER}
        size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
        requestOptions={{
          requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
        }}
        onAdFailedToLoad={(errorCode) => console.log(errorCode)}
       />
    </View>
  )
```

These are the commands I ran to get the app up and running:

eas build --profile development --platform android

npx expo start --dev-client